# Formula to show fee based off of a number

Tags: google-sheets-formula

non coder and rookie google sheet / excel spread sheet guy -

What I am trying to do is create a formula that will generate a fee based off of debt amount for example -

Debt Amount is 15000 or less = $1,595.00

Debt amount is 15001 or more = 12% of Debt so it should give me this number ($1,800.12)

I would like to fill out the cell and have the formula calculate based off of the number entered into the cell.

I have tried with regex Match but like I said I am rookie and still learning any and all help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in Advance

Aaron.

Answer (score 1):

`=ifs(F1<=0,0,F1<=15000,1595,F1>15000, F1*0.12)` # where F is the column for Debt Amount

Comment: That looks good :) ok now he will never learn to code, since Excel has nice one-line answers like that!

Comment: @ColeHenrich Conditional statements are must learn for everyone. He made disclaimer that he is new, so lets give him this one. Cheers!

Comment: @afaalgo Thank You So Much!! The formula works the only thin is when I put in $15,000 as the debt amount - I get the response of #N/A what do I need to do to correct that. Again thank you so much for the help. My brain doesn't hurt as bad lol

Comment: @AaronCarter Sorry I missed the F1<=15000 Updated my answer. Check Now.

Comment: @afaalgo - Thank you Very Much!!

Comment: @AaronCarter Accept the answers when you find it correct, so others can look directly.

Comment: @afaalgo You want to answer another one? 
I am trying to figure out how to count how many appointments confirmed from a particular lead source - Lead source is columns C, K, S from 2285 thru 2332 & C,K,S 2337 thru 2387 : Confirmed is Columns is F,N,V 2285 thru 2332 & F,N 2337 thru 2387

Any Idea on how to formula this??

Comment: @AaronCarter I would love to help.This is very hard to visualize. I would suggest create a sheet add the sample data and share it with me on anmolparida@gmail.com (read/write access)

Comment: @afaalgo   I will send the email to you shortly

Answer (score 0):

Look on google for articles about conditional math. I know you said you're not a coder, but coding works well for this. In any language, it would be this simple:
(I'm using java, but it is nearly the same in any language, with things as basic as conditional math).

```
    private int getFee(double debt){
       double fee = 0;
       if (debt <= 15000){
          fee = 1595;
       }
       if (debt >=15001){
          fee = 0.12*debt;
       }
       return fee;
    }
```

No joke, this is functional java code - I would just put it in a class. TBH, you could just send me the values and I could (well the computer could) calculate literally billions of debt values (not that you would ever need that much) in seconds. I'm serious about posting the stuff. If you want to have that calculator on hand - poke around in Java and see how it works.

I've updated it to now include everything you need in JavaScript - just replace the array values with your own. What this is doing is looping through each debtvalue in the debtarray, and using the getFee function to calculate the fee, then print it.

```
  let debtArray=[3456, 23456, 567, 546789, 
                 456789, 3456789, 56789, 567, 45678, 098,
                 0987, 0987, 876, 456, 3456, 283098, 23832];
            for (let index = 0; index < debtArray.length; index++) {
                const debtValue = debtArray[index];
                console.log(getFee(debtValue));  
            }
            function getFee(debt) {
                let fee = 0;
                if (debt <= 15000) {
                    fee = 1595;
                }
                if (debt >= 15001) {
                    fee = 0.12 * debt;
                }
                return fee;
            }
```

Comment: add a check if debt is greater than 0. use a else statement instead 2 ifs.